# How to analyse JavaScript class member coverage?

Tags: javascript, analysis

Is there a debugger, code analysis tool, or code editor, that can show me which member functions of an object (or class) are being called within the code, and ideally also help me see and visit the calling code?

For me I'm looking for tools to use with Firefox on Linux, but by all means share any tools as they'll be useful to someone!

Comment: Code coverage specifically means when testing software, how much of the code was tested by the test suite. Is this what you mean? (Here's one, http://blanketjs.org/, there are others.)

Comment: Yeah, I should have clarified. I do mean coverage, but not strictly for testing. I'm interested in knowing which member functions are being used in the code. My reason is that I have to port the object to a new API, and only need port functions that are actually called. However, I need to also look at each place a member is called - so a tool that can show me anywhere in the code calls any member of the object, so I can visit the calling code to see what it does. So its not a call stack, or step-through-debugger I need, but a code analysis tool.

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about your app? Frameworks, libaries, stacks, RESTful API etc? There are tools like [Angular batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) but that's Chrome only and why Firefox specifically?

Comment: Its pre-proof of concept, not for a single app, but aimed at providing a CouchApp style platform for a decentralised RESTful NoSQL storage system. The decentralised data store has a very basic REST API, pretty much just key/value store w versioning. Am considering re-implementing the CouchApp couchDB object to provide a CouchDB like API (a subset). So Chrome might be fine, I have Chromium but don't use it. I prefer Firefox on Linux. I can't give libraries and frameworks at this point as this is research. Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Firebug does that natively. I think what you're looking for is the JavaScript *call-stack* and *execution context* the best way that I know to do this is by using break points to stop the code right before execution and step through to see where a function is being invoked.

I'd recommend taking a closer look at the chrome dev tools as well. There is a pretty good course available for free on [Code School](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/discover-devtools/)

Here is an illustration of how this would work in DevTools bug the process is similar on Firebug

Source: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/async-call-stack/

[image]

## Update

[BlanketJS](http://blanketjs.org/) is probably your best bet, but here is a list of coverage tools that you may also want to take a look at.

- [istanbul](https://gotwarlost.github.io/istanbul/)
- [hrtimer](http://hrtimer.mozdev.org/)
- [jscoverage](http://siliconforks.com/jscoverage/)

**P.S.** You could always write your own but that's probably out of scope for what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it is helpful, because I need all the help I can get while learning :-) - but not what I'm seeking in this question which I see could have been clearer so I've added a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) or [Debugger in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger)